# JQuery var to form POST for PHP

Tags: php, jquery

To start off, sorry if this is a duplicate, or explained already.  I've read a minimum of 15 other topics that I assumed are similar to mine, yet I haven't had any success in getting it to work.

I currently have a form that is `action="submit.php"`.  The form is an order form (see Jfiddle link at bottom of post).  Inside *submit.php* I'm making an array of all `$_POST` values.  That works great.  Now the problem:

On the forum page (where user inputs), I have the following JQuery script that calculates totals.  There are 3 types of totals (all this is clear in the JFiddle).  The 3rd total, called "overallTotal", takes the sum of all "grandTotal"s and as of now, puts in `#overallTotal` ID.  I need that number to be included in the form submission (i.e., so it is accessible by $_POST).

Thanks in advance, and sorry again if this is repetitive.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rc694dzL/

```
    function oninput(e) {
        // process this row first
        var row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
        // explicitly cast to a number
        var quantity = +$(e.target).val();
        var price = +row.find(".val1").text();
        var output = row.find(".multTotal");
        var total = price * quantity;
        output.text(total);

        // now calculate total
        var subtotal = 0;
        var table = $(e.delegateTarget);
        table.find(".multTotal").each(function () {
            subtotal += (+$(this).text());
        });
        table.find(".grandTotal").text(subtotal);
        // now calculate overall total
        var overallTotal = 0;
        $(document).find(".grandTotal").each(function () {
            overallTotal += (+$(this).text());
        });
        $('#overallTotal').text(overallTotal);
```

Comment: _“I need that number to be included in the form submission”_ – then put it into a hidden form field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden input in your form like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="overallTotal" id="overallTotalInput">
```

and set the value from javascript like this

```
$('#overallTotalInput').val(overallTotal);
```

Now when submitting the form, the value will be stored into `$_POST['overallTotal']`

Answer (score 1):

Add some hidden fields in the form, and then populate the values with jquery.

Edit: tweaking your Fiddle now with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/dozecnp6/1/

1) Added the hidden input in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="OverallTotal" id="overallTotalField">
```

2) Added a bit to your `oninput()` function:

```
$('#overallTotalField').val(overallTotal);
```

Answer (score 0):

in this fiddle i can use `type="text"` you can change it to `type="hidden"`

check this 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rc694dzL/1/)